# database.php not found in cakephp setup

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm new to cakePHP, and I'm trying to make it works under linux mint.

I'have followed the cakephp website tutorial, but when I get to the database section I get this two warning on my page :

```
 Warning (2): include_once(/var/www/projects/app/Config/database.php) 
[function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory 
[CORE/Cake/Model/ConnectionManager.php, line 67]

Warning (2): include_once() [function.include]: 
Failed opening '/var/www/projects/app/Config/database.php' 
for inclusion 
(include_path='/var/www/projects/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') 
[CORE/Cake/Model/ConnectionManager.php, line 67]
```

And I can't get how to fix them.

But my database.php still is not found when I check /localhost/myProject

Answer (score 4):

You are in the wrong folder. Always navigate to your APP dir and call the cake console relativly from there

cd c:\wamp\www\project\app\
and execute the command in this folder

\Console\cake [command]

Answer (score 2):

Find the file **database.php.default** in your directory /var/www/projects/app/Config/
and rename this file to **database.php**

Comment: @Tiz did you check permissions for this file?

Comment: It needs to be in one of the include paths (/var/www/projects/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear) or the working directory of the script including it.

Comment: even if I try to put it in these path, it still tells me that I have no database.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your .htaccess files, It should be like this :

In your projects(root) folder :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
   RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In your projects/app folder :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

In your projects/app/webroot folder :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope, this may help you.

Comment: unluckly no, cakephp still telling me that database.php isn't there.